# Oracle select column names dynamically from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. Lets say **tab1** and **tab2**.

**tab1** has data like this:

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Field Name`**</kbd>
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`col1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`col63`</kbd>     
<kbd>`00002`</kbd>     <kbd>`col3`</kbd>      
<kbd>`00002`</kbd>     <kbd>`col47`</kbd>     
<kbd>`00003`</kbd>     <kbd>`col22`</kbd>     
<kbd>`00003`</kbd>     <kbd>`col40`</kbd>

Each **ID** has always **2 Field Name** values.

And **tab2** has columns **col1**,**col2**,**col3**,**col4**....**col70**

I want to select columns dynamically from tab2.

Like for **00001** it should be:

```
select col1,col63 from tab2;
```

Similarly for **00002** it should be :

```
select col3,col47 from tab2;
```

> Is there any way to achieve this without using function or procedure ? I am using Oracle 11G.

Comment: `case field_name when 'col1' then col1 when 'col2' then col2...`. Or in Oracle fashion: `decode(field_name, 'col1', col1, 'col2', col2, 'col3', col3)` no dynamic SQL and its vulnerability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the columns have compatible types, then you can do what you want by using `case` expressions:

```
select (case when t1.field1 = 'col1' then col1
             when t1.field1 = 'col2' then col2
             when t1.field1 = 'col3' then col3
             when t1.field1 = 'col4' then col4
        end),
       (case when t1.field2 = 'col1' then col1
             when t1.field2 = 'col2' then col2
             when t1.field2 = 'col3' then col3
             when t1.field2 = 'col4' then col4
        end)
from tab2 join
     (select id, min(fieldname) as field1, max(fieldname) as field2
      from t1
      group by id
     ) t1
     on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: the solution is great. but one thing , the tab2 has at least 70 columns, and the field name of tab1 may vary from col1 to col70.

Comment: @SayandipGhatak Then write 70 terms in the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Isn't there any solution like this :

select (select listagg(fieldname,',') from tab1 where id = '00001') from tab2

Comment: @SayandipGhatak SQL is a static language. Optimizer needs to built the execution plan, obviously, **before** the execution. How can it do this without column names?

Comment: @SayandipGhatak . . . You can generate the code using a SQL query or spreadsheet.